# Linux kernel bug? Create new socket defaults to non blocking

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, nonblocking

For a simple TCP Client code, the connect call returns EINPROGRESS without any nonblocking setup directive, and the send call returns EAGAIN. Here is the strace record for the process:

```
// ...
getsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \241\7\0\0\0\0\0", [16]) = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, {l_onoff=1, l_linger=0}, 8) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
futex(0x16487b0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \241\7\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \241\7\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(798), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.143.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
times(NULL)                             = 1718992611
sendto(4, "\f\0\0\0\206\0\0\0\0\213\1\203\1\0\0\0", 16, 0, NULL, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
getsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \241\7\0\0\0\0\0", [16]) = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, {l_onoff=1, l_linger=0}, 8) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04: `Linux test 4.15.0-65-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 17 17:06:04 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Is there something I'm missing or it is a bug?

Comment: There is a send timeout set, which in Linux also affects connect().

Comment: Yes, but it should not return EINPROGRESS even if the connection times out.

Comment: Don't mess around with SO_LINGER. Most of the time this is an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the socket(7) manual page

> ```
>    SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO
>           Specify  the  receiving or sending timeouts until reporting an error.  The argument
>           is a struct timeval.  If an input or output function  blocks  for  this  period  of
>           time, and data has been sent or received, the return value of that function will be
>           the amount of data transferred; if no data has been transferred and the timeout has
>           been  reached, then -1 is returned with errno set to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK, or EIN‐
>           PROGRESS (for connect(2)) just as if the socket was specified  to  be  nonblocking.
>           If the timeout is set to zero (the default), then the operation will never timeout.
>           Timeouts only have effect for system calls that perform socket I/O (e.g.,  read(2),
>           recvmsg(2),  send(2),  sendmsg(2)); timeouts have no effect for select(2), poll(2),
>           epoll_wait(2), and so on.
> ```

so by setting a timeout you may get an EAGAIN/EINPROGRESS result if the timeout expires.